# setValue:forUndefinedKey this class is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an nsmutablearray that looks like this:

```
(
        {
        caption = "";
        urlRep = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=6FC0C2DC-69BB-4FAD-9709-63E03182BEE1&ext=JPG";
    },
        {
        caption = "";
        urlRep = "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=324E4377-0BCD-431C-8A57-535BC0FC44EB&ext=JPG";
    }
)
```

And im trying to set the value of caption like this:

```
[[[self.form valueForKey:@"photos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] setValue:@"hi" forKey:@"caption"];
```

(`[self.form valueForKey:@"photos"]` is the array)

but I get :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0xa68ec40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key caption.'
```

**EDIT:**

If I use setObject forKey I get:

```
-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa6a88f0
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa6a88f0'
```

How do I fix this?

**CORRECT CODE TO FIX THIS:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *m = [[[self.form valueForKey:@"photos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] mutableCopy];
NSMutableArray *array = [self.form valueForKey:@"photos"];
[m setObject:textField.text forKey:@"caption"];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:m];
```

Comment: What does `setObject:forKey:` do?

Comment: @trojanfoe still crashes, added exact error to question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason you are getting the exception is because you have an array of `NSDictionary` objects, which don't respond to `setObject:forKey:` (or `setValue:forKey:`).

You probably want to convert them all to `NSMutableDictionary` objects as soon as you receive them.

Comment: How do I  go from an array of NSDictionary objects to NSMutableDictionary

Comment: @BluGeni Make a copy using `mutableCopy`.

Comment: got it, Thanks! I will post the exact code I used so it could help anyone that needs it.